# initramfs reports "compression not supported by kernel" for all compression types after 23.04 upgrade

Tags: initramfs

Just upgraded to 23.04 and initramfs won't install, reporting "compression (CONFIG_RD_*) not supported by kernel" for any of { gzip, bzip2, lz4, lzma, lzop, xz, zstd, cat }.  For example with 'cat' configured as the compression type I get:

```
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.184-37
grep: /boot/config-4.9.184-37: No such file or directory
W: cat compression () not supported by kernel, using gzip
grep: /boot/config-4.9.184-37: No such file or directory
E: gzip compression (CONFIG_RD_GZIP) not supported by kernel
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.9.184-37 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

Since it's unlikely that the kernel doesn't support any known compression method, including cat, I suspect it's a problem with initramfs.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please show us `dpkg -l  | egrep linux-'[g|h|i|m]'`

Comment: It's `ii  binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu 2.40-2ubuntu4 arm64 GNU binary utilities, for aarch64-linux-gnu target`.

Comment: Oh, and an additional comment, I've already tried the standard silly-walk of autoremove, clean, update, remove+install, etc.

Comment: Oh aarch64 then I am out.  Totally clueless about this. Sorry

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway.  I'll probably reflash it to recover since another day of working on it hasn't resolved the issue and it looks like it's going to be less work to reinstall than to continue, particularly since anything that causes it to reboot in the state it's in will result in a bricked system.

Comment: In my case, `echo "CONFIG_RD_ZSTD=y" > /boot/config-$(uname -r)` solved the problem. That said, I have `COMPRESS=zstd` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`, so I needed ZSTD support. Your case might differ